# Open Photoshop file in same directory as AppleScript

Tags: applescript, adobe, photoshop

I am trying to automate label generation from MS Excel into Photoshop using AppleScript. I can get all the data from Excel just fine, however getting that data into a predefined Photoshop document causes problems.

Specifically, I am unable to get Photoshop to open the template file which is located in the same folder as the AppleScript itself. I have tried numerous ways, including using a `tell finder`block like this

```
    tell application "Finder"
        set myFolder to container of (path to me) as text
    end tell
    set template_path to myFolder & "CC.psd"

    tell application "Adobe Photoshop"
        open template_path
    end tell
```

What sort of magic do I need to perform?

PS: Currently this is running on my local drive, however it would be awesome if it would work on network volumes as well.

Thank you

Tobias Timpe

Comment: What happens if you make line four like this: set template_path to alias (myFolder & "CC.psd"). In your code, template_path is just text whereas photoshop requires a file specification (as any app does). You might also try 'file' instead of 'alias'. Both can work over a network but alias depends upon the file existing — likely not a problem in your scenario, I guess.

Comment: With "alias" I get "Adobe Photoshop 2020 got an error: File some object wasn’t found." and with "file" I get "Can't get file (Insert path to file separated by colons)".

Comment: Try moving it inside the Finder tell block (i.e. make it the third line).

Comment: Given your current code just add the _`file`_ keyword, i.e. change `open template_path` to `open file template_path`. If you wanted to you can [do this](https://paste.ee/p/j1hL9).